# How to extract the text from a child node which is within a <div> tag through Selenium and WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

I need to get the value **107801307** that is inside a specific Div but there are several other Divs in the path before getting into that DIV I need. Can anyone help?
Below is the image with the information that I need to extract from the DIV.

[image: Div]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the *HTML* you have provided, to extract the text **107801307** you can use the following solution:

- *Java*:

  ```
  String myText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//b[@class='label_tratamento'][contains(.,'Ban Claro')]//following::span[1]").getAttribute("innerHTML");
  ```
- *Python*:

  ```
  myText = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//b[@class='label_tratamento'][contains(.,'Ban Claro')]//following::span[1]").get_attribute("innerHTML")
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Research xpath locators to find the specific element you want.

Assuming you were using Java, the code would be:

```
webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("//b[text()='Ban Claro']/following::span").getText();
```

or

```
webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("//b[@class='label_tratamento']/following::span").getText();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(("XPATH OF DIV HERE")[Index of the div where span is. Example: 4)/span)).getText();
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to include some description on how this answer help to solve the issue. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).